# How can I check if there is something in the dictionary in django template

Tags: python, django

I have the dictionary which i am passing to the template like this

```
dict['vars'] = ['a':'dd','b':'gg','c':'yy']
dict['myvars'] = ['a':'tt','b':'yy','c':'uu']
```

there are times

when the individual dict are empty with no key.

how can I check that like this

```
{%  if dict.vars empty   %}
do this
```

Comment: also suggest you do not use python `dict` function as variable name

Comment: Do I need to import the name "dict" in template file?I passed this dictionary named dict from views.py but my if condition doesn't work

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
{% if not dict.vars %}
  do this
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This could lead to an issue if vars would have the value False

Answer (score 11):

This:

```
{% if dict|length > 0 %} 
 do this
{% endif %}
```

should do the job just fine too.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do:

```
{% if not "vars" in dict %}
    Hello
{% else %}
    abc
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also check the dictionary empty or not like this

```
{% if not 'bool(video_url_dict)' %}
{% if 'bool(video_url_dict)' %}
```

This will work fine.